# Can I access a cookie from Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to set some user information in a cookie and be able to access it on connection, is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`client.request.headers.cookie` leads to race conditions as the cookie always points to the last logged in user.

Please see: [Socket.IO Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753957/socket-io-authentication).

Comment: Any evidence for that? The link you provided doesn't mention that.

Comment: 2016: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2470 Latest Docs: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-use-fn

Answer (score 39):

Using Socket.IO 0.8.7, you can access request headers via:

> socket.handshake.headers

You can find more detail on this at https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

Answer (score 4):

I got it, this works:

```
client.request.headers.cookie
```

Comment: According to this reply, this will work fine for development but break in production due to race conditions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4754814/371122

Answer (score 0):

After looking to the engine.io source code you can set cookies using:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);

io.use((socket, next) => {
    socket.conn.transport.once('headers', (headers) => {

        headers['set-cookie'] ="sess=test;"; });

    next();
});
```

this code could conflict with the engine.io code that set the sid cookie.
as both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 headers are case-insensitive and engine.io use 'Set-Cookie' in the headers object adding a lowercase object name 'set-cookie' would avoid this problem.