# Setting up httponly cookie in socket.io callback

Tags: session, cookies, socket.io, session-cookies

Im trying to avoid using express sessions and do user authentication with socket.io only (mean setting up and checking httponly cookies), but this code do not work:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('signin', function (data) {
        socket.request.headers.cookie = 'COOKIE=testcookie'; // do not work
    });
});

io.of('/logged').use(function (socket, next) {
    socket.request.headers.cookie; // Empty
});
```

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771337/adding-a-cookie-value-on-socket-io

Answer (score 1):

I check sources - there is no appropriate way to do this, so its beter to use express.cookie management instead