# How to send cookies to socket.io client from server?

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

On my client i do this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit('login', myLoginCode)
  }, [])
```

On server side previosly i did this:

```
app.get('login', (req, res) => {
      const cookieProtected = {
        maxAge: 946080000000,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: true
      } 
      res.cookie('id', login, cookieProtected)
      res.cookie('session', encryptSession, cookieProtected)
      res.cookie('logged', 'true', {
        maxAge: 946080000000,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: true
      })
})
```

But how can i do the same with socket?

```
  socket.on('login', loginCode => {
     // How to to place cookies in user browser from here?
    }
```

Maybe there is a way to send headers with socket.emit?

Comment: Did you try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771337/adding-a-cookie-value-on-socket-io?

Comment: io.on('connection', async socket => {
  try {
    socket.handshake.headers.cookie = 'test=1; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/'

Yes, it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There us no way to do it without rewriting IO library, so only option is to set cookies on client side.

Now i just verify user on server and send client cookies like an object, then on client i do like this:

```
document.cookie =
    'id=' +
    loginData.id +
    '; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; secure; samesite=strict; path=/'
```