# node.js socket.io get cookie value

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, cookies

i want to get cookie value in node server with socket.io

so every time socket send message to server i check the value of cookie

(i don't want session cookie) only in express i get the cookie by

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var cookie_id = req.cookies.userIDf;
  console.log(cookie_id);
   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

its work here but with socket.io i cant get cookie any solution ?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {


var cookief =socket.handshake.headers['cookie'];
  console.log(cookief); // its give me session  id not the cookies
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I access a cookie from Socket.io?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754232/can-i-access-a-cookie-from-socket-io)

Comment: @laggingreflex no body answer    

socket.handshake.headers.cookie

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) module to do this.

> npm install --save cookie

```
var cookie = require("cookie") //installed from npm;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    
    var cookief = socket.handshake.headers.cookie; 
    var cookies = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);    

});
```

`cookief` will return, but isn't accessible as a JSON object.

```
 io=5J1m_uXsDZvc61gTAAAA; userID=63kfh16tiu7md3ck7djv8856s0; userIDf=50
```

`cookies`, which parses `cookief` using `cookie.parse()`, will allow allow you to access each of the cookie values as a JSON object:

```
 cookies.io; //Returns 5J1m_uXsDZvc61gTAAAA
 cookies.userID; //Returns 63kfh16tiu7md3ck7djv8856s0
 cookies.userIDf; //Returns 50
```

or

```
 { io: 'RqIksBUQW4SM4zA4AAAA', userID: '63kfh16tiu7md3ck7djv8856s0', userIDf: '50' }
```

Comment: Where does `cookie.parse` come from?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie (for those wondering where `cookie.parse` comes from :)