# socket.io read browser cookies already set by php

Tags: php, cookies, socket.io

I set cookie token after login with php.

```
$authToken="kjhjgghfF&^*ghjfbv8756*7&*95576HJgf^%&";
setcookie('auth', $authToken, time()+60*60, '/');
```

The cookie is set to root path '/' and I see the cookie with EditThisCookie Chrome extension. Now I want to read this cookie with socket.io with each event.

```
var auth=socket.request.headers.cookies;
// socket.request.cookies - no success also
console.log(auth);
```

But getting 'undefined', because in headers dont't have cookies propertie.

Comment: It may be useful if we could see how and where you set the cookie in the PHP code

Comment: Ok. Code updated

Comment: Any of these answers any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754232/can-i-access-a-cookie-from-socket-io

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753957/socket-io-authentication