# Use Redis and Socket.io for user authentication

Tags: node.js, redis, express, authentication

I am learning to use redis and socket.io considering the number of advantages they have. In particular, I am trying to use them for user authentication too. I would appreciate if anyone explains with a simple code to give me an initial push. The framework I am using is express.
I read that express and socket.io cant talk to each other directly.

I found a related link about this [Socket.IO Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753957/socket-io-authentication) but I didnt quite understand how the db transactions are happening from the answer given there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/