# socket.io : associate browser and computer with the connection

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am writing a game in node.js with socket.io library. It has a server to whom 2 clients connect and play. My game is working fine, but there is a problem.

If a client that is already connected connects again to the game it is considered as 3rd connection request which messes things up.

This usually happens when I restart my node server when client browsers were not closed. I do I get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cookies. There are modules for this: [Socket.IO Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753957/socket-io-authentication)

But you can also do it manually, as it is a simple cookie:
When a user connects, add a step to **identify** the user before starting the game. This step should create a cookie or use the existing one and send it to the server for authentication.

It's not difficult, you can read and write cookies with javascript, and sending a String/number to the server is not a problem either (`websocket.emit('auth',whatever)`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on this example, it looks like its *possible* to use cookies to identify sessions in socket.io, but you may be better off using query string values to identify a particular browser or computer:

https://www.exratione.com/2013/05/the-use-of-cookies-versus-query-string-tokens-to-identify-sessions-in-socketio/