# Is node.js socket.io-client supposed to handle set-cookie

Tags: node.js, cookies, socket.io, cloud-foundry

Is the node.js socket.io-client supposed to automatically handle cookies?  That is, for all Set-Cookie response headers, is it supposed to pass back the corresponding Cookie headers during the handshake?

The reason I'm asking is because I have a proxy (the cloud foundry gorouter) between my client and 3 server instances.  The socket.io server is appropriately setting two cookies (JSESSIONID and **VCAP_ID**) on the response and I need the client to send them back appropriately so that affinity is kept by the gorouter.  I am currently getting connect failures due to a "transport error" when multiple instances of the server are running, but the problem goes away when I have a single server instance running.

Thanks in advance,
Keith

Comment: Hey, I'm in the same situation than you. Did you figure out how to send back cookies?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access cookies in socket.io check out the following.

http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.to('others').emit('an event', { some: 'data' });
});
```

Additionally check out this post on how to do authentication in socket. [Socket.IO Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753957/socket-io-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did get it to work, but the only node module I could get to work at the time was 'ws' as follows:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var webSocketUrl = ""wss://" + ...
var opts = { headers: { Cookie: 'JSESSIONID=1; __VCAP_ID__='+vcapID} };
var socket = new WebSocket(websocketUrl,opts);
```

-- Keith