# SocketIO - How to send data to a specific client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm having a problem sending data to a specific client.

Serverside

```js
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(app.get('port')));

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('onHabboConnection', function (data) {
      socket.id = data.id; 
      socket.join(data.id);
      io.sockets.in(data.id).emit('onHabboConnected');
    });
    
    socket.on('onHabboConnected', function (data) {
      console.log("<" + socket.id + "> " + data.username + " has joined the game.");
    });
});
```

Clientside

```js
   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
               $( document ).ready(function() {
   socket.emit('onHabboConnection', { id:'<%= user.id %>' });
  });

   socket.on('onHabboConnected', function () {
    console.log("WORKING" );
    socket.emit('onHabboConnected', { username: '<%= user.username %>'});
   });
```

```js
  io.sockets.in(data.id).emit('onHabboConnected');
```

I've attempted all over methods but they all throw errors.
This one doesn't throw an error but doesn't do anything!

Comment: *"I've attempted all over methods but they all throw errors."* did you try socket.emit? if so, please list all the other "methods" you attempted that failed along with their errors to reduce the amount of guesswork.

Comment: `socket.emit()` works fine for this case. What was the error thrown?

Comment: io.sockets.in(data.id).emit('onHabboConnected'); is not sending to the client.

Comment: BUMP, ANYONE PLEASE?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the unique identifier `socket.id` that was generated on the client side. That's why you are emitting but it's not going anywhere since that client doesn't exist:

```
socket.on('onHabboConnection', function (data) {
  //socket.id = data.id;  remove this
  socket.join(data.id);
  io.sockets.in(data.id).emit('onHabboConnected');
});
```

If you want to change `socket.id` , then change it on client side.

Comment: But won't another user be able to change the userid through clientside?

Comment: socket id is uniquely generated session identifier for a client. Why do you need to change it?

Comment: in that case, change it from client side. But yes another user might be able to change it. Probably you need to add some authentication like mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753957/socket-io-authentication)

Comment: I'm using, socket.emit to send to the specified incoming client. Is that okay?