# Socket.IO service with API Gateway technic

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using microservices technic with node js and express, i used API Gateway(node js service that support https) that transfer the api requests to the other services, also i'm using SocketIO as a node js service.

**I would like to know what will be the best way to securely connect  to the socket IO service from the client if i used API Gateway technic.**

**There is two approach that i'm considered:**

1. Use the socketIO service as a independent service without go through from API Gateway.
2. some way to transfer from  API Gateway to socketIO service

Any advise from someone that solved this case?

Comment: It's abit  unclear what you're asking, most likely a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753957/socket-io-authentication?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for the response @Lawrence Cherone, i want to know what is the best approach for connecting from the client to my node js server that contain the socketIO logic. The different between the question that you sent me is that i want to secure all my microservices under api gateway service and i would like to know if it is possible to connect to socketIOService through API Gateway or i need to do a separate connection.
I don't need to use redis in this point.