# Manage multiple tab in webrtc

Tags: tabs, socket.io, webrtc

With all the samples  I have, opening a tab will create a new peer. I am writing an application allowing logged in member to chat (a little more simple than anonymous). My question is : should/can I force multi tabs, or even multi browsers  of that same member (he login Firefox and Chrome at the same time)  to use just one connection (ICE, STUN...etc...)

I see that people can handle that in socketio [Manage multiple tabs (but same user) in socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166187/manage-multiple-tabs-but-same-user-in-socket-io)

P/S: I think I am gonna use socketio as signaling server.
Thanks!