# Node.js cluster and socket.io with mongodb as store

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I've got a problem to set up clustered **node.js / socket.io** app, with socket.io store, based not on Redis but on MongoDB.
I need to mention that my app uses Mongo to store data. So I don't want to setup another DB just to make soket.io works across multiple process.

I found an option - [mong.socket.io](https://npmjs.org/package/mong.socket.io), but it looks like I can't make this work with node clusters.
I'm using **node: 0.10.10**, with **socket.io: 0.9**
I'm looking for any solution that will let me use MongoDB as a store for socket.io that runs on separate processes.

*Counting on you, thanks.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any of clustered worker can easily access MongoDB using [mongodb](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) or mongoose in order to get required data. As well it can store that data locally as a cache.
Once socket.io client is connected it will be bound to one of workers and will not swap workers during execution.
In order to share sessions you need to create session middleware for socket.io that will ask for session details from MongoDB from one of the workers. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4755045/1312722) answer which explains how to access session data in socket.io from shared session details. And in order to make it clustered, instead of MemoryStorage use [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) that allows to store session data within mongo and it will make session details shared over workers.