# Get PHP $_SESSION from NodeJs

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I'm trying to check the username in the NodeJs chat with the user session. Is there a   secure way to do it? (My NodeJs server isn't in the same place as the host of the website). I'm using this code NodeJs + express to do the chat application.

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(), 
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { log: false });

server.listen(8080);

app.get('/chat.js', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('chat.js');
});

/* CHAT FUNCTIONS */

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('send', function (data) {
        // I wanna get the user session
        // something like this:
        // (code below does not exist)

        var username = session['username'];

        console.log(username + " is here.");
        io.sockets.emit('message', data);
    });

});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You really don't want to be sending session data across the internet *especially with the username* without tunneling it through an encrypted protocol (e.g. HTTPS).

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4755045/2119660) about session storage w/ socket.io?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use common storage for sessions e.g. `memcached` or `redis`.
Than u will have common access.