# Session Management Socket.io

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, socket.io

I'm trying to implement sessions in my `node.js` app which makes heavy use of `socket.io`. I'm struggling with this currently, and found a rather simple solution which recommends using the socket itself to store the session information. For example:

```
socket.on('login', function(username) {
   if (loginSuccessful() {
       socket.sessionID = generateSessionId();
   }
});

socket.on('logout', function(username) {
       socket.sessionID = null;
});
```

I am worried that such a simple solution wouldn't be secure, however, I'm not sure if there is any clear vulnerability this solution would have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [socket.io and session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641053/socket-io-and-session)

Comment: I've seen that before, this isn't the same thing - I'm asking about the vulnerabilities of a particular approach, not about how to use express and socket.io for session management (that's the complicated approach I'm trying to avoid)